# gcc 4.4 vs. Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, gcc, ubuntu

I am somewhat confused, need some C/C++ guru here. If it is C and in principle the language cannot change then how come some programs run on Visual C++ and not on gcc ???

I am using Visual C++ 2008 and gcc 4.4.1 and trying to compile some really old code (1996). It somewhat works with Visual C++ (Windows XP) and completely fails with gcc (Ubuntu 9.10).

What alarms me is that if it is C/C++, then the compiler should not be an issue. Any help ?

**UPDATE** : This is the code, http://www.ece.unh.edu/robots/cmacdemo.c

Comment: I guess you have some platform specific parts or compiler specific macros/functions in it. plz post at least the entry function (main, winmain). What are the errors?

Comment: @mbx: Not necessarily. There are plenty of instances where GCC's tighter adherence to the specification in newer versions can cause old code to fail to compile.

Comment: 1996 is quite old.  It was a time when writing code using some features like template which worked on several compilers needed lot of knowledge about each of them in order to avoid points badly handled.  And the language description wasn't stable yet.  I'd not be surprised for instance if the STL wasn't yet in the current draft.

Comment: BTW, which compiler was used in the first place?

Comment: @mbx : The documentation said microsoft compilers (I presume Visual Studios)

Comment: I don't see any C++ code - cmacdemo.c looks like C, as you might expect, and it uses non-standard headers such as <conio.h>

Comment: @Paul R : It is C, is that the problem ?

Comment: @Arkapravo: not a problem, *per se*, but you refer to "C/C++" in your question, whereas this looks like a question about porting Windows-specific C code.

Comment: @Paul R: Well, the code would be pretty cool once it works, but it is pretty old - so I am giving it a shot. Yeah ! ... C not C++, sorry for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to compile and link, under gcc on linux:

- as already pointed out, change the "\" to "/" in the `#include` file names
- change `#include "io.h"` to `#include "sys/io.h"`
- comment out `#include "conio.h"`, it is not on linux and doesn't seem to have been needed
- comment out the Windows-only flag `O_BINARY` in file unh_cmac.c

Comment: Great Job - I will give it a try. Just because I am a lazy bastard, can you send the edited files to my email, arkapravobhaumik at gmail dot com ? .... many thanks ! ... :-)

Comment: Yep ! .... it is all linking to give me a cmacdemo.o file but not giving me executables ....

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious problem is:

```
#include <sys\types.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
```

The `\` is allowed by Visual Studio, as the Windows dir separator, but not by gcc on Linux/Unix, where the directory separator is `/`.

`/` should work everywhere though, so I suggest changing those over.

Then you should add the compile errors so we can see what/if problems remain.

Answer (score 3):

The language *specification* cannot change, but how closely a compiler *follows* those specifications *can*.

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of factors:

- `C` and `C++`, as defined by their respective standards, are evolving;
- the level of standard adherence varies from compiler to compiler;
- both `gcc` and Visual C++ have non-standard extensions, which -- if used -- would cause compability problems with other compilers;
- each operating system has its own APIs, so code written for Windows XP won't necessarily compile on Ubuntu, and vice versa.

It is impossible to tell from your question what combination of these is causing problems in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I get the picture. I have added the link for the code

Answer (score 2):

Without some example code, one can only guess.

Anyways, a common reason is non-standard code that worked by accident back with whatever compiler was used to develop the code, and better diagnostics in newer compilers prohibit it, or better optimizations in newer compilers compile the code so that it behaves differently than the original author intended.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile with gcc because it uses windows specific headers, like "conio.h" etc. and windows specific directory delimiters, like "\" instead of "/".

Comment: So, the code is window specific ! .. eh ? it may be better to stick to windows ??